# C# Use variable from loop in next loop run

Tags: c#, winforms, while-loop

I have a problem with my winforms application and I didn`t find a way to solve it: I am running a while loop which is fetching a value from a webserver.
Then this value should be substracted from the value which was fetched by the loop the run before.

```
while(true)
{
 valuecurrent = webclient.DownloadString("http://ipadress/value");

 double result = (valuebefore - valuecurrent); 
}
```

Is there a way to save the value from the run before and use it in the next run of the loop?

Thanks in advance!
Tim

Comment: Store it in a variable outside of the loop..

Comment: I think you could use another variable and set it to valueCurrent at the end of each loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a variable outside/before the loop and set it on each pass.

```
var valuebefore = 0;

while(true)
{
 valuecurrent = webclient.DownloadString("http://ipadress/value");

 double result = (valuebefore - valuecurrent);

 valuebefore = valuecurrent;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for asking. That was really easy, but I didn`t thought about this option because it was too easy and I thought that it wont work. I don`t know why. Thank you !

Comment: Thank you for respectively typing 'valuebefore' as a var, many people would have just used the immutable double

Comment: @MadMyche, `var valuebefore = 0;` will initialize variable of type `int`

Comment: I was simply showing a basic example of what he was looking for. It is up to him to determine the data type he wants.

Answer (score 0):

```
        // Assign a null value before
        double? valuebefore = null;
        while (true)
        {
            // Get the current value from the webserver
            valuecurrent = webclient.DownloadString("http://ipadress/value");

            // Use the current value if we don't have any previous values
            // Subtract the current value from previous value if it exists
            double result = valuebefore.HasValue == false
                ? valuecurrent
                : valuebefore.Value - valuecurrent;

            // Save the result to our value before to be used in next loop
            valuebefore = result;
        }
```

You can leverage nullable types and a simple if/then logic to save the first value then subtract subsequent values.